# Xml line break not read in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert xml file to html use xslt But i can't get xml line break in html file.line break character not read in my xslt file.How to get this break in html file.i try to use  slove this problem but it not work.i get error massage to xml-params can't use inside xml-if.

### Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <inv:Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:inv="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:us="http://unicornsolutions.com">
        <UBLExtensions xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
            <UBLExtension xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
                <ExtensionContent>
                    <us:ExtensionFields>
                        <us:Doctype>DW</us:Doctype>
                        <us:ActivityCode>20143</us:ActivityCode>
                        <us:Custom>
                            <us:Interest>
                                <us:InterestDetails>
                                    <us:BaseItemDetails>
                                        <us:LineItemNum>1</us:LineItemNum>
                                        <us:Reference>11610</us:Reference>
                                        <us:Description>InterestItem</us:Description>
                                        <us:Amount>2000.00</us:Amount>
                                        <us:FromDate>2019-08-16</us:FromDate>
                                        <us:ToDate>2019-10-16</us:ToDate>
                                        <us:NumberOfDays>61</us:NumberOfDays>
                                        <us:InterestRate>8.75</us:InterestRate>
                                        <us:InterestAmount>29.25</us:InterestAmount>
                                    </us:BaseItemDetails>
                                </us:InterestDetails>
                                <us:InterestSummary>
                                    <us:TotalAmount>29.25</us:TotalAmount>
                                </us:InterestSummary>
                            </us:Interest>
                        </us:Custom>
                        <us:InvoiceSummary>
                            <us:InvoiceTotals>
                                <us:LineItemTotalsAmount>2229.25</us:LineItemTotalsAmount>
                                <us:DiscountTotalsAmount>0.00</us:DiscountTotalsAmount>
                                <us:ChargesTotalsAmount>0.00</us:ChargesTotalsAmount>
                                <us:TaxTotalsAmount>0.00</us:TaxTotalsAmount>
                                <us:GrossAmount>2229.25</us:GrossAmount>
                                <us:VatTotalsAmount>0.00</us:VatTotalsAmount>
                                <us:NetAmount>2229.25</us:NetAmount>
                                <us:RoundingAmount>0.00</us:RoundingAmount>
                            </us:InvoiceTotals>
                        </us:InvoiceSummary>
                    </us:ExtensionFields>
                </ExtensionContent>
            </UBLExtension>
        </UBLExtensions>
        <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
        <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol5a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.difi.no:ehf:faktura:ver2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
        <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii05:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
        <cbc:ID>1000790</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:IssueDate>2019-10-16</cbc:IssueDate>
        <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
        <cbc:TaxPointDate>2019-08-15</cbc:TaxPointDate>
        <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listID="ISO4217">NOK</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
        <cac:InvoicePeriod>
            <cbc:StartDate>2019-10-16</cbc:StartDate>
            <cbc:EndDate>2019-10-30</cbc:EndDate>
        </cac:InvoicePeriod>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>2019-10-30</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>LetterDueDate</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>0.00</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>BOFee</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>0.00</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>DCFFee</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>0</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>Noofdaystilldcf</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>1000790</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>DebtorPortalUserName</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>J85JZTE</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>DebtorPortalPassword</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>0.00</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>PaidAmount</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>2229.25</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>Balance</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>B2BFairEHF</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>H1</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>Viser til faktura fra Vegamot AS - Avtale. &#10;

    De ikke har mottatt betaling fra deg, og Fair Collection AS sender deg derfor denne betalingsoppfordringen. &#10;

    På denne siden av arket vil du finne faktura- og betalingsinformasjon. På baksiden kan du lese om hvordan vi best mulig kan hjelpe deg via vår kundeportal. </cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>H1P1</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>D35F1C43-752D-4BD6-90CB-7F6E5C4D83F8</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>DocumentReference</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>DEBT_COLLECTION_NOTICE</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>DocType</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>11000790540</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>KID</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>2019-10-30</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>PaymentDueDate</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>20143</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>ActivityCode</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
            <cbc:ID>0.00</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:DocumentType>PaymentDueAmount</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
            <cac:Party>
                <cac:PartyIdentification>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">935162718</cbc:ID>
                </cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cac:PartyName>
                    <cbc:Name>Vegamot AS - Avtale</cbc:Name>
                </cac:PartyName>
                <cac:PostalAddress>
                    <cbc:CityName>OSLO</cbc:CityName>
                    <cbc:PostalZone>0483</cbc:PostalZone>
                    <cac:AddressLine>
                        <cbc:Line>0483 OSLO</cbc:Line>
                    </cac:AddressLine>
                    <cac:Country>
                        <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">NO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                    </cac:Country>
                </cac:PostalAddress>
                <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                    <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="NO:VAT">935162718MVA</cbc:CompanyID>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                    <cbc:RegistrationName>Vegamot AS - Avtale</cbc:RegistrationName>
                    <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">935162718</cbc:CompanyID>
                </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            </cac:Party>
        </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
            <cac:Party>
                <cac:PartyIdentification>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">997850211</cbc:ID>
                </cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cac:PartyIdentification>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="ZZZ">cid:80398215</cbc:ID>
                </cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cac:PartyName>
                    <cbc:Name>Tluk-Transport</cbc:Name>
                </cac:PartyName>
                <cac:PostalAddress>
                    <cbc:CityName>TILLER</cbc:CityName>
                    <cbc:PostalZone>7091</cbc:PostalZone>
                    <cac:AddressLine>
                        <cbc:Line>Tonstadbrinken 95</cbc:Line>
                    </cac:AddressLine>
                    <cac:AddressLine>
                        <cbc:Line>7091 TILLER</cbc:Line>
                    </cac:AddressLine>
                    <cac:Country>
                        <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">NO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                    </cac:Country>
                </cac:PostalAddress>
                <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                    <cbc:RegistrationName>Tluk-Transport</cbc:RegistrationName>
                    <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">997850211</cbc:CompanyID>
                </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cac:Contact>
                    <cbc:ID>80398215</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:Name>Tluk-Transport</cbc:Name>
                </cac:Contact>
            </cac:Party>
        </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:PayeeParty>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">920999360</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Fair Collection AS</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:CityName>Oslo</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>0412</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line>Postboks 45 Torshov</cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line>0412 Oslo</cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">NO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Fair Collection AS</cbc:RegistrationName>
                <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">920999360</cbc:CompanyID>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:PayeeParty>
        <cac:PaymentMeans>
            <cbc:PaymentMeansCode listID="UNCL4461">31</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
            <cbc:PaymentDueDate>2019-10-30</cbc:PaymentDueDate>
            <cbc:PaymentID>11000790540</cbc:PaymentID>
            <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="BBAN">15061356735</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
        </cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cac:PaymentMeans>
            <cbc:PaymentMeansCode listID="UNCL4461">31</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
            <cbc:PaymentDueDate>2019-10-30</cbc:PaymentDueDate>
            <cbc:PaymentID>11000790540</cbc:PaymentID>
            <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="IBAN">NO3515061356735</cbc:ID>
                <cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
                    <cac:FinancialInstitution>
                        <cbc:ID schemeID="BIC">DNBANOKK</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:FinancialInstitution>
                </cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch>
            </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
        </cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
            <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>Collection Amount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
            <cbc:Amount currencyID="NOK">200.00</cbc:Amount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UNCL5305">E</cbc:ID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
            <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>Other Cost</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
            <cbc:Amount currencyID="NOK">0.00</cbc:Amount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="UNCL5305">E</cbc:ID>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="NOK">0</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="NOK">2229.25</cbc:TaxableAmount>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="NOK">0</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UNCL5305">E</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
                    <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>Not applicable</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="NOK">2029.25</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="NOK">2229.25</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
            <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="NOK">2229.25</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
            <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="NOK">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
            <cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="NOK">200.00</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount>
            <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="NOK">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
            <cbc:PayableRoundingAmount currencyID="NOK">0.00</cbc:PayableRoundingAmount>
            <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="NOK">2229.25</cbc:PayableAmount>
        </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NAR" unitCodeListID="UNECERec20">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="NOK">2000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <cbc:AccountingCost>565656565</cbc:AccountingCost>
            <cac:InvoicePeriod>
                <cbc:StartDate>2019-08-01</cbc:StartDate>
                <cbc:EndDate>2019-08-15</cbc:EndDate>
            </cac:InvoicePeriod>
            <cac:OrderLineReference>
                <cbc:LineID>0</cbc:LineID>
            </cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cac:Item>
                <cbc:Name>MainAmount</cbc:Name>
                <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UNCL5305">E</cbc:ID>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            </cac:Item>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="NOK">2000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            </cac:Price>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:ID>248583</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="DAY" unitCodeListID="UNECERec20">61</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="NOK">29.25</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <cac:InvoicePeriod>
                <cbc:StartDate>2019-08-16</cbc:StartDate>
                <cbc:EndDate>2019-10-16</cbc:EndDate>
            </cac:InvoicePeriod>
            <cac:OrderLineReference>
                <cbc:LineID>565656565</cbc:LineID>
            </cac:OrderLineReference>
            <cac:Item>
                <cbc:Name>Interest</cbc:Name>
                <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                    <cbc:ID schemeID="UNCL5305">E</cbc:ID>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
                    <cbc:Name>Amount</cbc:Name>
                    <cbc:Value>2000.00</cbc:Value>
                </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
                <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
                    <cbc:Name>InterestRate</cbc:Name>
                    <cbc:Value>8.75</cbc:Value>
                </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
            </cac:Item>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="NOK">175.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:BaseQuantity>365</cbc:BaseQuantity>
            </cac:Price>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
    </inv:Invoice>
```

### Xslt File ##

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:inv="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">

        <xsl:template match="/">

            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
    <body  style = "background: white;
      width: 21cm;
      height: 29.7cm;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 0.5cm; ">
    <xsl:for-each select="inv:Invoice/cac:AdditionalDocumentReference">
    <xsl:if test="cbc:DocumentType = 'H1P1' ">
      <xsl:value-of select="cbc:ID"/>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Line breaks aren't significant in either HTML, XSLT, or XML. If you want an HTML line break use `<br/>`. You could put that `xsl:if` condition into the `xsl:select` pattern and save some iterations.

Comment: i want to covert xml code to html.xml file paragarph have line break.this line break did't get in xslt file.'&#10;'

Comment: Ah well you have to add an `<ENTITY .../>` declaration into the DOCTYPE declaration of your .xslt. There are questions and answers here about this, have a look around.

Comment: In HTML rendering to ensure a line break you either need to use a `br` element or you need to use the `pre` element (https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) and/or CSS `white-space: pre` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on your element container. So your XML to HTML transformation using XSLT will need to make sure it produces HTML with the right elements and/or CSS settings if you want line breaks to be rendered. In general, if you ask for help here, consider to use minimal samples to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: have you tried using apply-tempaltes select="cbc:ID" instead of value-of?

Comment: "i get error massage to xml-params can't use inside xml-if" -- I strongly suspect that is not the actual error message (or massage), I suspect it is referring to xsl:param and xsl:if, and since you are being careless in quoting the error message I suspect you are also being careless in showing us the XSLT code and that your actual XSLT code contained an `xsl:param` in the wrong place.